# Not getting text content using cypress

Tags: text, cypress

Using cypress I am trying to get text from all the header elements in a table but showing error

I have tried text/inner text /textcontent etc same issue.

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.its() errored because the property: 'outerText' does not exist on your subject.

```
 cy.wrap($table).find('th').each(($header)=>{
 cy.wrap($header).its('outerText').then((Text)=>{
 cy.log(Text);
})
```

i expect text Gender on this case

[image]

This is my cy.wrap yielded object

[image: cypress runner -subject yeilded]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since Cypress is yielding `jquery` instances, you'll need to unwrap it first to access a native dom element property:

```js
cy.get('#my-el').should($el => {
  expect($el[0].outerText).to.contain('Gender')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by using invoke and .then

Now i am getting the text i wanted
    cy.wrap($header).invoke('text').then(($elementvalue)=>{
                    cy.log($elementvalue);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 cy.window().then((win) => {
      console.log(
        win.document.querySelector(".minimal_filter_tags").textContent
      );
    });
```